# Stationarity and AR(p) representation

Tags: time-series, stationarity

I know that covariance stationary processes can always be represented as an $MA(\infty)$ process, i.e.
$$ Y_t  = \alpha +  \sum_{s=0}^{\infty} \beta_{s} \varepsilon_{t-s}. $$
with uncorrelated innovations $\varepsilon_t^2 \sim (0,\sigma^2)$ and conditions on $\{\beta_s\}_{s=0}^{\infty}$. Is there an analogous theorem showing that we can represent any stationary process as an $AR(\infty)$ process of the following form?
$$ Y_t = \delta + \sum_{s=1}^{\infty} \gamma_s y_{t-s} + \varepsilon_t.$$
If so, could you provide a source or a name of a theorem?

Comment: Do you mean strict stationarity?

Comment: I'd be interested in either weak or strong stationarity, depending on which results are available.

Comment: I have adjusted the language so that innovations are uncorrelated rather than i.i.d., so that the process is covariance stationary.

Comment: Writing an AR(p) as an MA(inf) can only be done if it’s causal. Writing an MA(q) as an AR(inf) can only be done if it’s invertible. These definitions are usually described in any time series textbook.

Comment: Thanks: here my goal is to describe *any* stationary process as an AR(inf), not merely an MA(q).